# How can I view the call stack of a running process/thread?

Tags: windows, troubleshooting

Someone asked me to get a **call stack** or **stack trace** of a running process so that he could analyze it for me.

How can I get that information?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. Get [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).
2. Enable **Show Details for All Processes** from the **File** menu:

   [image]
3. In the main pane, select the process you're interested in:

   [image]
4. Open the context menu (right-click) for the selected process and click **Properties**:

   [image]
5. On the **Threads** tab, you'll be able to see a list of the running threads inside that process:

   [image]
6. Select the thread you're interested in and click the **Stack** button:

   [image]
7. Process Explorer will now display the current call stack for the selected thread:

   [image]

### Symbols

If your troubleshooting requires you to get more detail, it is often very helpful to load debugging *symbols* into Process Explorer. This is how:

1. If you don't already have a Windows debugger installed, you're going to have to install the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) first.
2. In Process Explorer, open **Configure Symbols...** from the **Options** menu:

   [image]
3. If you have the Debugging Tools (or another Windows debugger) installed, Process Explorer will automatically find the `dbghelp.dll` file. Otherwise, set the correct path here.

   [image]

   The **Symbols path** should look something like:

   ```
   SRV*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
   ```

   The only part you'll want to adjust is `C:\Symbols`. That's the location where the debugging symbols will be cached.

Comment: is there a way to dump all threads call stacks to file?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a stack of clr process, you can use ProcInsp (I'm its developer, the tool is free for use).

1. Install [ProcInsp](https://github.com/CUSTIS-public/ProcInsp)
2. Find the process you are interested in and click on it
   [image: List of processes]
3. Click on the thread (note, that ProcInsp shows app's entry point as the name of the thread - it skips all frames of .net infrastructure)
   [image: List of threads]
4. The stack trace with entrypoint highlighted is shown
   [image: Stacktrace]