# win 8.1 explorer eating CPU when opening "Device and Printers"

Tags: windows-8.1, cpu, windows-explorer

I'm facing a peculiar issue that I can't fix. I discovered recently that my Win 8.1 Update 1 (with all updates through WSUS offline) starts eating all the CPU when opening "the device and printers" window.

There's a 5-10' delay until the devices appear however the CPU keeps on spinning even after the icons are displayed for about 5-10' more minutes.

Xperf file (thanks to @magicandre1981 for instructions) is posted on [Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23699575/xperf/HighCPUUsage.zip) - 24MB zip unpacked to 145MB.

Looking through Sysinternals process explorer it seems the problem is caused by `MultiByteToUnicodeN` call (unfortunately I cannot post an image):

`ntdll.dl!RtlMultiByteToUnicodeN+0x1cf0
ntdll.dl!RtlMultiByteToUnicodeN+0x1cf0
ntdll.dl!RtlMultiByteToUnicodeN+0x1cf0
ntdll.dl!RtlMultiByteToUnicodeN+0x1cf0
ntdll.dl!RtlMultiByteToUnicodeN+0x1cf0
SHCORE.dll!GetScaleFactorForDevice+0x1d4
FunDisc.dll!DllCanUnloadNow+0x2e8
SHCORE.dll!GetScaleFactorForDevice+0x1d4
SHCORE.dll!GetScaleFactorForDevice+0x1d4
windows.immersiveshell.serviceprovider.dll!
SHCORE.dll!GetScaleFactorForDevice+0x1d4
SHCORE.dll!GetScaleFactorForDevice+0x1d4
SHCORE.dll!GetScaleFactorForDevice+0x1d4
SHCORE.dll!GetScaleFactorForDevice+0x1d4
Explorer.EXE`

Any ideas how to fix this? Either I wait 20' or so or have to kill the explorer task. I've tried reinstalling all the devices to no avail; for some reason rendering this window causes the unicode translation to eat all the CPU.

**Update with symbols**

Based on the comment received, I've installed the *retail* symbols for windows 8.1 and pointed process explorer (as explained in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/462989/how-can-i-view-the-call-stack-of-a-running-process-thread) to it however the output looks pretty much the same. I've looked at the stack for a thread and it seems it is spending most of its time in the synchronizing on one object: 

`ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x2246
ntoskrnl.exe!KeRemoveQueueEx+0x108e
ntoskrnl.exe!KeRemoveQueueEx+0xae9
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x22a
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSetBasePriorityThread+0x4ec
ntoskrnl.exe!KeRemoveQueueEx+0x281d
ntoskrnl.exe!KiCheckForKernelApcDelivery+0x23
ntoskrnl.exe!SeQuerySessionIdToken+0x1b99
ntoskrnl.exe!SeQuerySessionIdToken+0x15f9
ntoskrnl.exe!SeQuerySessionIdToken+0x1440
ntoskrnl.exe!FsRtlAllocateExtraCreateParameter+0x744e
ntoskrnl.exe!FsRtlAllocateExtraCreateParameter+0x52c4
ntoskrnl.exe!FsRtlAllocateExtraCreateParameter+0x13c8
ntoskrnl.exe!FsRtlAllocateExtraCreateParameter+0x10da
ntoskrnl.exe!IoDeleteAllDependencyRelations+0x14d0
ntoskrnl.exe!FsRtlAllocateExtraCreateParameter+0xa96
ntoskrnl.exe!FsRtlAllocateExtraCreateParameter+0x898
ntoskrnl.exe!ObReferenceObjectByHandleWithTag+0xe92
ntoskrnl.exe!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56
ntoskrnl.exe!setjmpex+0x34b3
ntdll.dll!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0xa
KERNELBASE.dll!GetModuleHandleExA+0xb6
KERNEL32.DLL!DeviceIoControl+0x80
cfgmgr32.dll!SwMemFree+0x6a7
KERNELBASE.dll!SetKernelObjectSecurity+0xc1
ntdll.dll!RtlAcquireSRWLockExclusive+0x31e
ntdll.dll!RtlMultiByteToUnicodeN+0x20a3
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d`

Here's another stack from one of the initiating threads (`SHCORE.dll!GetScaleFactorForDevice`):

`ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x2246
ntoskrnl.exe!KeRemoveQueueEx+0x108e
ntoskrnl.exe!KeRemoveQueueEx+0xae9
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x22a
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSetBasePriorityThread+0x4ec
ntoskrnl.exe!KeRemoveQueueEx+0x281d
ntoskrnl.exe!KiCheckForKernelApcDelivery+0x23
win32k.sys+0x12aaea
win32k.sys+0x6d10d
win32k.sys+0xca699
win32k.sys+0x35a9f
win32k.sys+0x2a514
win32k.sys+0x138e28
win32k.sys+0x19fa8
win32k.sys+0x4921e
ntoskrnl.exe!setjmpex+0x34b3
USER32.dll!WindowFromPhysicalPoint+0x1a
USER32.dll!CallWindowProcW+0x2bf
USER32.dll!SendMessageW+0x111
UxTheme.dll!DrawThemeParentBackgroundEx+0x18f
Comctl32.dll!ImageList_GetIconSize+0xee3
Comctl32.dll!ImageList_GetIconSize+0x1107
Comctl32.dll!DrawScrollBar+0x12bf
USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW+0x154
USER32.dll!CallWindowProcW+0x132
Comctl32.dll!DefSubclassProc+0xb2
Comctl32.dll!DefSubclassProc+0x77
explorerframe.dll!Ordinal111+0x655d
Comctl32.dll!DPA_GetPtr+0x282
Comctl32.dll!DPA_GetPtr+0x152
USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW+0x154
USER32.dll!OffsetRect+0x172
USER32.dll!OffsetRect+0x22d
ntdll.dll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x1f
USER32.dll!WindowFromPhysicalPoint+0x1a
USER32.dll!CallWindowProcW+0x2bf
USER32.dll!SendMessageW+0x111
UxTheme.dll!DrawThemeParentBackgroundEx+0x1a6
explorerframe.dll!Ordinal111+0xabef
explorerframe.dll!Ordinal111+0x6ae5
USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW+0x154
USER32.dll!OffsetRect+0x172
USER32.dll!OffsetRect+0x22d
ntdll.dll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x1f
USER32.dll!WindowFromPhysicalPoint+0x1a
USER32.dll!CallWindowProcW+0x2bf
USER32.dll!SendMessageW+0x111
UxTheme.dll!DrawThemeParentBackgroundEx+0x1a6
explorerframe.dll!Ordinal111+0xaa52
Comctl32.dll!DPA_GetPtr+0x282
Comctl32.dll!DPA_GetPtr+0x152
USER32.dll!GetWindowLongPtrA+0x265
USER32.dll!OffsetRect+0x172
USER32.dll!OffsetRect+0x22d
ntdll.dll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x1f
USER32.dll!SendMessageW+0x1aa
USER32.dll!SendMessageW+0x1bc
explorerframe.dll!Ordinal111+0x546e
explorerframe.dll!Ordinal111+0x10568
explorerframe.dll!Ordinal111+0x11d50
explorerframe.dll!Ordinal111+0x11d00
explorerframe.dll!Ordinal111+0xeee3
SHELL32.dll!SHGetKnownFolderPathWorker+0x84c
SHELL32.dll!SHGetKnownFolderPathWorker+0xa23
SHCORE.dll!GetScaleFactorForDevice+0x333
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d`

Note it took 30' or so this time around - had time to install the symbols, read the posts, do some diagnostics and post back and still have the CPU jacked up..

**Second Update for symbols**

Thanks to @kinokijuf, I have used the Windows Defender Debug.dll and have more accurate info. The Threads now look as follows:

`ntdll.dll!TppWorkerThread
ntdll.dll!TppWorkerThread
ntdll.dll!TppWorkerThread
ntdll.dll!TppWorkerThread
ntdll.dll!TppWorkerThread
SHCORE.dll!Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase::MarshalInterface+0x1c
SHCORE.dll!Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase::MarshalInterface+0x1c
FunDisc.dll!CNotificationQUeue::ThreadProc
SHCORE.dll!Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase::MarshalInterface+0x1c
windows.immersiveshell.serviceprovicer.dll!CImmersiveShellController::s_ImmersiveShellComponentsThreadProc
Explorer.EXE!wWinMainCRTStartup`

While the top level threads still show thread/lock contention ?:

`ntoskrnl.exe!KiSwapContext+0x76
ntoskrnl.exe!KiSwapThread+0x14e
ntoskrnl.exe!KiCommitThreadWait+0x129
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x22a
ntoskrnl.exe!KiSchedulerApc+0x74
ntoskrnl.exe!KiDeliverApc+0x1fd
ntoskrnl.exe!KiSwapThread+0x2da
ntoskrnl.exe!KiCommitThreadWait+0x129
ntoskrnl.exe!KeRemoveQueueEx+0x27b
ntoskrnl.exe!IoRemoveIoCompletion+0x8a
ntoskrnl.exe!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0x30a
ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
ntdll.dll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xa
ntdll.dll!TppWorkerThread+0x286
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d`

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have symbols loaded for everything? Cause to me it seems you don’t

Comment: How can I check what symbols are loaded or what are the ones that are missing? Sorry if the question doesn't make sense - I'm not familiar with Windows internals...

Comment: Nevermind, figured out what you meant. I've installed the _retail_ symbols for windows 8.1 and pointed process explorer (as explained in [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/462989/how-can-i-view-the-call-stack-of-a-running-process-thread) to it however the output looks pretty much the same.

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the cpu usage and share the trace: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD

Comment: You don’t have symbols. A correct stack trace would not show functions like `Ordinal111`.

Comment: You need to configure your debugger to use the copy of `dbghelp.dll` in `%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\` — this version supports symbols unlike the one in system32

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've updated the post with the xperf file.

Comment: @kinokijuf thanks for the info - I've updated the post with the 'rich' symbols loaded and posted the new stacks.

Comment: Aaaand now you see it has nothing to do with `MultiByteToUnicodeN`.

Comment: the CPU usage comes from opening a lot of Registry keys. Use this command instead: **xperf -on latency+REGISTRY+REG_HIVE -stackwalk profile+RegQueryKey+RegEnumerateKey+RegEnumerateValueKey+RegDeleteKey+RegCreateKey+RegOpenKey+RegSetValue+RegDeleteValue+RegQueryValue+RegQueryMultipleValue+RegSetInformation+RegFlush+RegKcbCreate+RegKcbDelete+RegVirtualize+RegCloseKey -buffersize 1024 -MaxFile 1024 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d HighCPUUsageRegistry.etl** This shows me details about the registry operations

Comment: @magicandre1981 Uploaded the output to [Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23699575/xperf/HighCPUUsageRegistry.zip). It's a pretty big file - 1GB (though the zip is only 64MB).

Comment: @kinokijuf I've updated the title of the post accordingly. Incredible what a difference the symbols make...

Comment: Explorer reads several thousand time data from **REGISTRY\MACHINE\System\ControlSet001\Control\DeviceClasses** and this causes the high CPU usage for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the CPU usage comes from reading a lot of registry keys from `MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\DeviceDisplayObject\InterfaceClass\{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}\DeviceDisplayStatus` (over 4000 calls).

[image]

I also see a lot of calls to `MACHINE\System\ControlSet001\Control\DeviceClasses\{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}` where I see over 5700 HarddiskVolumeSnapshot ( like `REGISTRY\MACHINE\System\ControlSet001\Control\DeviceClasses\{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}\##?#STORAGE#VolumeSnapshot#HarddiskVolumeSnapshot5753#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}\#\Properties`).

All those calls make Explorer so slow. Try to figure out why you have so many Snaphots and reduce the amount to make Explorer faster.

Comment: Any idea though what causes these calls? The snapshots are caused by backups - I can remove them but they seem cheap. As for the `{53f..}` that Interface class seems to be related to USB devices however I'm unclear why this huge number of calls (or retries) especially as the entry does not exist in the registry... Forgot to say thanks for your patience and time so far!